# Networking from afar

Tags: software-industry, networking

I'm trying to leave Houston, where I found my foot in the door in software development, and move back to Seattle, where all of the friends I still keep in touch with are in non-IT companies.

Needless to say, my IT/development network is not ripe, however the one "in" I have led to an interview (no offer).

This leads me to believe that networking is the best way to go, but how can I build my Seattle IT network while living in Houston?

Comment: Here is one idea: join the meetups in Seattle. Hook up with the organizers, the presenters and anyone who is interesting to you. Become recognizable.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - Are there remote meetups? Tough to commute from Houston to Seattle.

Comment: @JeffO The OP doesn't have to commute. I am a New Yorker, and I get meetup announcements from SF. I haven't networked with the folks from SF yet - I am doing plenty in NYC as is, but I'll find an excuse to do it. Most meetups are videotaped and every meetup has a discussion section - who knows, the OP might run into someone they went to school with :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - tough to network with someone on a videotape ;)

Comment: @JeffO But then, that's what the discussion forums for each meetup group are for - the alternative to not communicating would be "if a tree falls in a forest and nobody sees it fall, did the tree fall?" :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build up your employability value is not networking, and definitely not LinkedIn.

The best way is to create instructional technical blogs, to which you could point your prospective employers and interviewers.

Your blog helps you jot down steps you took to

- implement ideas
- solve issues
- understand a new technology or technique
- warn of potential pitfalls
- riddles you encountered which you are currently trying to solve.

You should break-down the problems your solved or issues encountered into single-issue granularity, without mentioning or describing what project you had been performing. Set up a different blog for different categories of issues: sysadmin and system scripting, java, c#, perl, database, etc.

Your blogs would definitely help people who are searching online for solutions.

They would allow your prospective employers to get a good grip on your technical value.

We also have to realise that it would be costing employers 5 X or more than if they had farmed out the jobs to India, Southeast Asia or South America.

There is actually very low value in networking in increasing the value of your employability. How much assurance would your networking provide above technical blogs written by your own hand?  At worst, it would give an impression you are spending too much time on social networks.

As technology grows more and more complex, the value of networking in helping you get a job is diminishing. Employers need to get to know your value with the highest degree of confidence by spending the shortest initial amount of time figuring out if you are worth investigating.

Answer (score -1):

For technology, even more important than "who you know" it is what can you do. Before considering any huge moves like moving out of state, build up your portfolio and make yourself a strong candidate. I believe by doing this, you will find that you may not have to move at all.

Being successful in technology, particularly in software development is less about education or networking and more about practice, practice, practice! Build, create, repeat until you no longer have to seek jobs. Jobs will come to you. Recruiters are a good way of finding jobs and building networks too.

Comment: The OP is not stating that they *have to* move to Seattle, but *want to*. Your advice may be valid, but the answer to the question is a bit thin.